# Unable to remove header

Tags: react-native

For some reason I am not able to remove the header at the very top of my React Native app (see screenshot).

The app itself is contained in the `AppMain` component:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <PrincipalContextProvider>
      <AppMain />
    </PrincipalContextProvider>
  );
};
```

which produces this (note the white header at the top).

[image]

I am making use of components like `react-navigation/native-stack` and `react-navigation/bottom-tabs` which may produce something like this. But after setting `screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}` on everything, and even removing the app content entirely:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>The text..</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I'd still get this:

[image]

Apparently, there's something else causing this and I am not sure what.

Comment: To give a better answer I need to see more code and need to get more info about your project. Is your project an react-native or an managed expo project, which versions are you using ?

Try to replace the imports ```react-navigation/native -stack``` with ```react-navigation/stack```

Comment: @MichaelBahl It's a React Native app. For local development I run it under `npx expo run:android --no-build-cache`. I can replace the imports, but since I am only rendering a single `Text` element, I am not sure if that is the cause for this.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without code of the ```react-navigation``` setup.

Comment: @MichaelBahl What setup? If I remove the entirety of the app and only render the `Text` componoent, then there shouldn't be a `react-navigation` component involved. What I just noticed: I used to to see the clock and the battery status at the top. One more thing to mention is that I added `nativewind` today but I don't think this can cause this.

Comment: Maybe you can set ```androidNavigationBar``` to ```visible:false``` in app.json

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you set the `flex` and `height`?

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{height: '100%', flex:1}}> // Add style={{height: '100%', flex:1}}
      <Text>The text..</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to put it in a `Screen` component, put it in your navigator `Stack.Navigator` instead

```
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            }}
          >
            ...
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={login} />
            ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do with this component. It looks to me as if this header is _always_ there no matter what as can be seen when I only render a `Text`.

Comment: Have you tried it on your Navigator component? Are you using react-navigation?